# Generate javascript file on the fly in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-2, dygraphs

Friends,

I am trying to use DyGraph in my application. Please look at the code below -

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9">
    <title>crosshairs</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph-combined.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
  </head>
```

The code uses data.js file containing function to get some static data. 
I want data.js to be generated using a controller method so that it will generate data using database.

Can anybody help me out to resolve this issue.

Thanks for sharing your valuable time.

Comment: Here is similar question with more elegant solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092473/dynamically-generated-javascript-css-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could define a controller action:

```
public ActionResult Data()
{
    // Obviously this will be dynamically generated
    var data = "alert('Hello World');";
    return JavaScript(data);
}
```

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Action("Data", "SomeController") %>"></script>
```

If you have some complex script that you don't want to generate in the controller you could follow the standard MVC pattern by defining a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    ... put required properties
}
```

a controller action which would populate this view model and pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Data()
{
    MyViewModel model = ...
    Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

and finally a view which in this case will be the javascript representation of the view model (`~/Views/SomeController/Data.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MyViewModel>" %>
alert(<%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Name) %>);
```

Comment: Thanks Darin for your quick reply and detailed explanation. +1 for that.

Comment: Javascript files generated this way aren't compressed. I'm betting it has something to do the request not ending in .js and iis.

Answer (score 1):

**Full Disclosure**

- This answer is copy/pasted from another question:

  - [Dynamically generated Javascript, CSS in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092473/dynamically-generated-javascript-css-in-asp-net-mvc)
- This answer is similar to other answers here.

  - This answer uses `cshtml` pages rather than `ascx` controls.
  - This answer offers a View-Only solution rather than a Controller-Only solution.
  - I don't think my answer is 'better' but I think it might be easier for some.

**Dynamic CSS in a CSHTML File**

I use CSS comments `/* */` to comment out a new `<style>` tag and then I `return;` before the closing style tag:

```
/*<style type="text/css">/* */

    CSS GOES HERE

@{return;}</style>
```

**Dynamic JS in a CSHTML File**

I use JavaScript comments `//` to comment out a new `<script>` tag and then I `return;` before the closing script tag:

```
//<script type="text/javascript">

    JAVASCRIPT GOES HERE

@{return;}</script>
```

**MyDynamicCss.cshtml**

```
@{
var fieldList = new List<string>();
fieldList.Add("field1");
fieldList.Add("field2");

}

/*<style type="text/css">/* */

@foreach (var field in fieldList) {<text>

input[name="@field"]
, select[name="@field"]
{
    background-color: #bbb;
    color: #6f6f6f;
}

</text>}

@{return;}</style>
```

**MyDynamicJavsScript.cshtml**

```
@{
var fieldList = new List<string>();
fieldList.Add("field1");
fieldList.Add("field2");
fieldArray = string.Join(",", fieldList);

}

//<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    var fieldList = "@Html.Raw(fieldArray)";
    var fieldArray = fieldList.split(',');
    var arrayLength = fieldArray.length;
    var selector = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        var field = fieldArray[i];
        selector += (selector == '' ? '' : ',')
                    + 'input[name="' + field + '"]'
                  + ',select[name="' + field + '"]';            
    }
    $(selector).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(selector).addClass('disabled');
});
@{return;}</script>
```

**No Controller Required (using Views/Shared)**

I put both of my dynamic scripts into `Views/Shared/` and I can easily embed them into any existing page (or in `_Layout.cshtml`) using the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">@Html.Partial("MyDynamicCss")</style>
<script type="text/javascript">@Html.Partial("MyDynamicJavaScript")</script>
```

**Using a Controller (optional)**

If you prefer you may create a controller e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Action("MyDynamicCss", "MyDynamicCode")">
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Action("MyDynamicJavaScript", "MyDynamicCode")"></script>
```

Here's what the controller might look like

**MyDynamicCodeController.cs (optional)**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyDynamicCss()
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/css";
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyDynamicJavaScript()
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
    return View();
}
```

**Notes**

- The controller version is not tested.  I just typed that off the top of my head.
- After re-reading my answer, it occurs to me it might be just as easy to comment out the closing tags rather than use the cshtml `@{return;}`, but I haven't tried it.  I imagine it's a matter of preference.
- Concerning my entire answer, if you find any syntax errors or improvements please let me know.