# Control Browser Caching of Generated JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, browser-cache

**Background**

An MVC 4 application needs to include JavaScript that is generated from the database.  The generated file is relatively large, and changes only occasionally (changes every 2-10 days).

The accepted answer of

[Generate javascript file on the fly in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8133546/141172)

provides a good framework for generating the JavaScript.  However, the URL of the JavaScript resource is static.  As I understand it, the browser will cache that resource.  That caching can be controlled by the `OutputCacheAttribute`.

**Question**

How can I cause the browser cache to expire whenever the generated JavaScript changes, similar to the way that bundles work?  A `SqlDependency` for the `OutputCacheAttribute` is not an option.

Comment: Version query string in the script URL? E.g. `foo.js?v=1234567`. (When your JS file changes, append a different query string. This forces the browsers to request it.)

Comment: Alternatively, name the javascript file something to do with the date it was generated.

Comment: @ColinDeClue: The name of the JavaScript resource is the URL of the controller, is it not?  Not sure how to give the JavaScript resource a different name.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: The file doesn't have well-defined "versions".  The database is queried when the JavaScript must be constructed.

Comment: @EricJ. Hm, the timestamp when the DB was last queried could serve as the version identifier...

Comment: A mere guess but I'd give a go to the common _random query string_ method as in @Šime Vidas's comment. Just to see what happens if you append `?something` to that resource name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar situation, and what I do is append a random Guid to the end of the query string in the script tag every time I regenerate the JavaScript file.

For Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/generated.js?id=7c97aa32-29d9-dd11-a926-001d096d84f2"></script>
```

You could use a random string or even a time-stamp, as long as the query parameter is changed,the new script file will be downloaded.

Comment: I don't really want to generate a static file, but rather have a controller action return the JavaScript (which would be cached).  I guess I could apply the same principal using a hash of the generated script or the generation timestamp.

Comment: You're right, the same principal will work for a non-static file. As long as there's a change in the query string appended to the static url of the JavaScript resource the browser will download the updated file. A time-stamp or hash should both do the trick.